# pass sql result to mako template and show in table

Tags: html, sql, mako

I just decided to learn Pyramid and choose Mako as template language. I got a list from view which is a raw sql result, as follow:
[{'sample': 'R1_Y200.fq', 'study': 'GaoQiang1'},{'sample': 'R1_Y300.fq', 'study': 'GaoQiang2'},...]

```
view.py:
@view_config(route_name='example', renderer='example.html')
def templet_test(request):
    ...
    return {'result':search_result}

html:
<html>
...
<table border="1" width="500" align="center" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <th >study</th>
  <th >sample</th>

</tr>
% for item in result: 
<tr>
<td valign=top align=center> ${item['study']} </td>
<td valign=top align=center> ${item['sample']} </td>
</tr>
% endfor
</table>
...
</html>
```

But it didn't work out. I got this message:
"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected internal server error

(generated by waitress)"

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work out"? Did you get an error message? Did it do nothing?

Comment: "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected internal server error

(generated by waitress)"

Answer (score 0):

The real exception is shown in console - it will contain the cause of your problem.
You may also want to enable debug toolbar in pyramid to have a more friendly way of error handling in development.

Also by looking at your template - and i assume you use sqlalchemy for database interaction, your probably want to access result rows like item.study , not like item['study'].

That's as much as I can guess without a proper traceback.

Comment: Thx, I've found my problem. It's a setting problem~